# Crawled/Mapped Properties w/SharePoint Online

Tags: search, filter, people-search, sorting, crawl

I am trying to customize the People directory in my SharePoint Online Search Center. I have a few properties mapped to fields that sync from my company's active directory to Office 365, such as last name and office location. I've tried creating properties (for refining and sorting) that are mapped to *LastName*, *Office*, *Location*, *BaseOfficeLocation*, and *OfficeNumber*. I have tried waiting almost two weeks for a full crawl and re-indexed several times, but only get about 70% of my employees to display when sorted by last name or filtered by office. Is this a limitation of SharePoint Online or am I going about this incorrectly?

Thank you very much,

Nick

Answer (score 0):

People properties (and BCS properties) have to be created at the tenant (or farm for on premises) level. I suspect that you created your properties in a Site Collection.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The properties were created correctly, but still no luck after opening a ticket with Microsoft and working with them for almost a week.